# Update form input with django form value

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to pass legacy db entries to django form.

I created the model by using django inspectdb method.

Similar to:

```
class Form(models.Model):
    date_entered = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_needed = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    client = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    project_no = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    map_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

I have create the corresponding view in views.py.

```
def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Form, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

In my post_edit.html.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="client" value= '{{ form.client.value }}' required/>
<input type="text" name="projectno" class="form-control" value= '{{ form.project_no.value }}' required/>
..
<input type="text" name="jobcontact" class="form-control" value='{{ form.contact.value }}' required/>
```

**Client** and **project_no** work (produce values on the form) while **contact** does not.  I have verified the name in model and also the existance of a value for this in the db table.

Should I pass something else for these input values.  I am new to django.  Help please.

EDIT: Adding class PostForm().  As identified in the accepted answer only 2 fields had been added to class PostForm().  After adding the remainig classes the form populated the values.

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Form
        fields = ('project_no', 'client',)
```

Comment: Could you please show PostForm class?

Comment: I think that settles it.  Thanks @igors